# Issues installing ghostscript with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I've been having issues trying to install ImageMagick-6.8.6-9 w/ ghostscript-9.10.

I've installed ghostscript with the prefix "./configure --prefix=/usr/local/" and tested the "gs" and it returns

```
"GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting."
```

When I try to install ImageMagick, I type in the commands:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib, /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/lib"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/lib

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-gslib --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/ --with-perl-optons=PREFIX=/usr/local/php53
```

This returns:

ImageMagick is configured as follows. Please verify that this configuration
matches your expectations.

```
    Host system type: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    Build system type: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

                      Option                        Value
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes           yes
    Static libraries  --enable-static=yes           yes
    Module support    --with-modules=no             no
    GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=yes             yes
    Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16       16
    High Dynamic Range Imagery
                      --enable-hdri=no              no

    Delegate Configuration:
    BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes              yes
    Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no           no
    Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default        none
    DJVU              --with-djvu=yes               yes
    DPS               --with-dps=yes                no
    FFTW              --with-fftw=yes               no
    FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes                no
    FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes         yes
    FreeType          --with-freetype=yes           yes
    GhostPCL          None                          pcl6 (unknown)
    GhostXPS          None                          gxps (unknown)
    Ghostscript       None                          gs (9.10)
    Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts//
    Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=yes              no
    Graphviz          --with-gvc=no
    JBIG              --with-jbig=yes               no
    JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes               yes
    JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=yes                yes
    LCMS v1           --with-lcms=yes               yes
    LCMS v2           --with-lcms2=yes              no
    LQR               --with-lqr=yes                yes
    LTDL              --with-ltdl=yes               no
    LZMA              --with-lzma=yes               no
    Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes   yes
    MUPDF             --with-mupdf=no               no
    OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes            yes
    PANGO             --with-pango=yes              yes
    PERL              --with-perl=no                no
    PNG               --with-png=yes                yes
    RSVG              --with-rsvg=no                no
    TIFF              --with-tiff=yes               yes
    WEBP              --with-webp=yes               no
    Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=      none
    WMF               --with-wmf=no         no
    X11               --with-x=                     yes
    XML               --with-xml=yes                yes
    ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes               yes

    X11 Configuration:
          X_CFLAGS        = 
          X_PRE_LIBS      = -lSM -lICE
          X_LIBS          = 
          X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 

    Options used to compile and link:
      PREFIX          = /usr/local
      EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
      VERSION         = 6.8.6
      CC              = gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
      CFLAGS          = -pthread -I/usr/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/include/lqr-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
      CPPFLAGS        = -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6
      PCFLAGS         = -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
      DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
      LDFLAGS         = 
      MAGICK_LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/lib 
      LIBS            = -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljasper -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lpng12 -ldjvulibre -lfontconfig -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -pthread -lIlmImf -lz -lImath -lHalf -lIex -lIlmThread -pthread -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp
      CXX             = g++
      CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -pthread
      FEATURES        = DPC OpenMP
      DELEGATES       = bzlib djvu mpeg fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pango png ps tiff x xml zlib

Then I'll type "make" and "sudo make install."

After the installation, I've gathered some information:

$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.6-9 2013-09-19 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pango pangocairo png png tiff x xml zlib

$ convert -list configure

Path: /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.6//config-Q16/configure.xml

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC             gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
CFLAGS         -pthread -I/usr/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/include/lqr-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CODER_PATH     /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.6/modules-Q16/coders
CONFIGURE      ./configure  '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-gslib' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/' '--with-perl-optons=PREFIX=/usr/local/php53'
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/
COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS       -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6
CXX            g++
CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      bzlib djvu mpeg fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pango png ps tiff x xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/ --with-gvc=no --with-mupdf=no --with-rsvg=no --with-wmf=no --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6
EXEC-PREFIX    /usr/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/bin
FEATURES       DPC OpenMP
FILTER_PATH    /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.6/modules-Q16/filters
HOST           x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
INCLUDE_PATH   /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6
LDFLAGS        -L/usr/local/lib 
LIB_VERSION    0x686
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,8,6,9
LIBRARY_PATH   /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.6
LIBS           -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljasper -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lpng12 -ldjvulibre -lfontconfig -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -pthread -lIlmImf -lz -lImath -lHalf -lIex -lIlmThread -pthread -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp
NAME           ImageMagick
PCFLAGS        -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PREFIX         /usr/local
QuantumDepth   16
RELEASE_DATE   2013-09-19
SHARE_PATH     /usr/local/share/ImageMagick-6
SHAREARCH_PATH /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.6/config-Q16
SVN_REVISION   13089
TARGET_CPU     x86_64
TARGET_OS      linux-gnu
TARGET_VENDOR  unknown
VERSION        6.8.6
WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FEATURES       OpenMP 
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16



$ convert -list delegate

Path: /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml

Delegate                Command
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    blender =>          "blender" -b "%i" -F PNG -o "%o""\n"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
        cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
        cgm =>          "ralcgm" -d ps -oC < "%i" > "%o" 2> "%Z"
 dng:decode =>          "ufraw-batch" --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"
        dot =>          "dot" -Tsvg "%i" -o "%o"
        dvi =>          "dvips" -q -o "%o" "%i"
        eps<=>pdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        eps<=>ps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=nodevice" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        fig =>          "fig2dev" -L ps "%i" "%o"
        hpg =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
       hpgl =>          "hp2xx" -q -m eps -f `basename "%o"` "%i";     mv -f `basename "%o"` "%o"
        htm =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
       html =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
      https =>          "curl" -s -k -o "%o" "https:%M"
       ilbm =>          "ilbmtoppm" "%i" > "%o"
        jxr =>          "mv "%i" "%i.jxr"; "JxrDecApp" -i "%i.jxr" -o "%o.pnm"; mv "%i.jxr" "%i"; mv "%o.pnm" "%o"
        man =>          "groff" -man -Tps "%i" > "%o"
       miff<= show      "display" -delay 0 -window-group %[group] -title "%l " "ephemeral:%i"
mpeg:decode =>          "ffmpeg" -v -1 -i "%i" -vframes %S -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"
        pdf<=>eps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        pdf<=>ps        "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=nodevice" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
        plt =>          "echo" "set size 1.25,0.62; set terminal postscript portrait color solid; set output \'%o\'; load \'%i\'" > "%u";"gnuplot" "%u"
        png<= webp      "cwebp" -quiet -q %Q "%i" -o "%o"
        pnm<= ilbm      "ppmtoilbm" -24if "%i" > "%o"
        pnm<= jxr       "mv "%i" "%i.pnm"; "" -i "%i.pnm" -o "%o.jxr"; mv "%i.pnm" "%i"; mv "%o.jxr" "%o"
        pnm<= wdp       "mv "%i" "%i.pnm"; "" -i "%i.pnm" -o "%o.jxr"; mv "%i.pnm" "%i"; mv "%o.jxr" "%o"
        pov =>          "povray" "+i%i" -D0 "+o%o" +fn%q +w%w +h%h +a -q9 "-kfi%s" "-kff%n";"convert" -concatenate "%o*.png" "%o"
         ps<=>eps       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=epswrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
         ps<=>pdf       "gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite" "-sOutputFile=%o" "-f%i"
         ps<= print     "lpr "%i"
       rgba<= rle       "rawtorle" -o "%o" -v "%i"
       scan =>          "scanimage" -d "%i" > "%o"
      scanx =>          "scanimage" > "%o"
      shtml =>          "html2ps" -U -o "%o" "%i"
        sid =>          "mrsidgeodecode" -if sid -i "%i" -of tif -o "%o" > "%u"
        svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
       tiff<= launch    "gimp" "%i"
        txt<=>ps        "enscript" -o "%o" "%i"
        wdp =>          "mv "%i" "%i.jxr"; "JxrDecApp" -i "%i.jxr" -o "%o.pnm"; mv "%i.jxr" "%i"; mv "%o.pnm" "%o"
       webp =>          "dwebp" -pam "%i" -o "%o"
```

When I run:

```
$ convert test.pdf test.jpg
convert: Postscript delegate failed `test.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/682.
convert: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.
```

I've also installed ghostscript first and then ImageMagick.  Can't figure out what the problem is because in the ./configure it does pick up that ghostscript version

```
"Ghostscript       None                          gs (9.10)"
but "Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=yes              no"
```

I also don't notice it in the delegate.xml.

How do I resolve this or update the delegate to have the ghostscript accounted for?  I've tried to rebuild/reinstall multiple times.

This is on a linux 64 bit machine hosted on dreamhost

---------------------- UPDATE -------------------------------------------
So the problem is actually with the type of pdf and ghostscript.  The underlying issue isn't with ImageMagick but with the ghostscript itself.

It has to deal with a specific pdf file.  When i test it with others, it works.  I need to find one that doesn't have private information (pdf) so that I can post it.

Below is the error:

Executed this command

```
$ "gs" -dDEBUG -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=peachjar.jpg"` 


START 0 1539248 242651 1301992 20148 true 543 3 <0>
END PROCS 0 1559432 270087 1322176 26044 true 665 3 <0>
gs_std_e.ps 0 1588032 292042 1322176 28524 true 673 3 <0>
gs_il1_e.ps 0 1608216 300680 1322176 28524 true 674 3 <0>
END FONTDIR/ENCS 0 1608216 300908 1322176 28524 true 676 3 <0>
END DEVS 0 1652560 350323 1322176 28524 true 680 3 <0>
END STATD 10 1652560 357399 1322176 31404 true 685 3 <0>
END GS_FONTS 10 1702864 405991 1322176 31404 true 733 3 <0>
END BASIC COLOR 20 1702864 412637 1322176 31404 true 753 3 <0>
END IMAGE 20 1743232 430628 1322176 31404 true 758 3 <0>
gs_btokn.ps 20 1743232 437016 1322176 31404 true 762 3 <0>
gs_dps1.ps 20 1743232 440716 1322176 31404 true 764 3 <0>
gs_dps2.ps 20 1743232 445465 1322176 31404 true 765 3 <0>
gs_type1.ps 20 1763416 453120 1322176 31404 true 773 3 <0>
gs_lev2.ps 20 1792016 488997 1418792 128740 true 779 3 <0>
BEGIN RESOURCES 20 1792016 491563 1418792 128740 true 779 4 <1>
END CATEGORY 20 1792016 494182 1418792 129028 true 780 5 <1>
END GENERIC 20 1801952 511799 1418792 129028 true 782 4 <1>
END FIXED 20 1822136 525178 1418792 129028 true 782 4 <1>
END MISC 20 1842320 536448 1418792 129028 true 782 4 <1>
END ENCODING 20 1842320 539678 1418792 129028 true 782 4 <1>
gs_resmp.ps 30 1862504 560012 1418792 129028 true 786 3 <1>
gs_res.ps 30 1862504 557912 1418792 129028 true 786 3 <0>
gs_typ42.ps 30 1862504 559024 1418792 129028 true 789 3 <0>
gs_cidfn.ps 30 1882688 580725 1418792 129028 true 797 3 <0>
gs_cidcm.ps 30 1902872 603726 1418792 129028 true 797 3 <0>
gs_fntem.ps 30 1971840 659861 1418792 129236 true 799 3 <0>
gs_cidtt.ps 30 1992024 676379 1418792 129236 true 799 3 <0>
gs_cidfm.ps 30 1992024 679831 1418792 129236 true 799 3 <0>
gs_cmap.ps 30 1992024 690035 1418792 129236 true 804 3 <0>
gs_setpd.ps 30 2012208 708143 1418792 129236 true 804 3 <0>
gs_typ32.ps 30 2012208 710172 1418792 129236 true 802 3 <0>
gs_frsd.ps 30 2040808 727746 1418792 129236 true 802 3 <0>
gs_ll3.ps 30 2081176 758534 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
gs_mex_e.ps 30 2081176 761224 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
gs_mro_e.ps 30 2081176 762319 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
gs_pdf_e.ps 40 2081176 763418 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
gs_wan_e.ps 40 2081176 764494 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
pdf_ops.ps 40 2101360 787780 1418792 129236 true 803 3 <0>
gs_l2img.ps 40 2101360 790762 1418792 129236 true 806 3 <0>
pdf_rbld.ps 40 2101360 795591 1418792 129236 true 818 3 <0>
pdf_base.ps 40 2141728 825841 1418792 129236 true 1015 4 <0>
pdf_draw.ps 40 2230880 900681 1418792 129236 true 1015 4 <0>
pdf_font.ps 50 2251064 936749 1418792 129956 true 1016 4 <0>
pdf_main.ps 50 2336928 1014744 1418792 129956 true 1023 4 <0>
pdf_sec.ps 50 2336928 1024953 1418792 129956 true 1023 4 <0>
gs_css_e.ps 50 2357112 1029974 1418792 129956 true 1023 4 <0>
gs_cff.ps 50 2430504 1098514 1418792 129956 true 1025 4 <0>
gs_mgl_e.ps 50 2430504 1100126 1418792 129956 true 1025 4 <0>
gs_agl.ps 50 2869632 1512857 1418792 129956 true 1026 4 <0>
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /product @ 184
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /Delta @ 198
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /greaterequal @ 179
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /lessequal @ 178
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /integral @ 186
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: cannot insert /Euro @ 219 used for /currency
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /infinity @ 176
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /notequal @ 173
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /summation @ 183
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /apple @ 240
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /approxequal @ 197
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /lozenge @ 215
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /radical @ 195
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /Omega @ 189
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /pi @ 185
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: insert /partialdiff @ 182
gs_ttf.ps 60 2983888 1641027 1418792 129956 true 1061 4 <0>
gs_icc.ps 60 3004072 1647206 1418792 129956 true 1062 4 <0>
gs_dps.ps 60 3012488 1662879 1418792 130450 true 1075 4 <0>
gs_dpnxt.ps 60 3012488 1664433 1418792 130450 true 1092 4 <0>
gs_epsf.ps 60 3012488 1670674 1418792 130450 true 1104 4 <0>
gs_fapi.ps 60 3012488 1673807 1418792 130450 true 1104 4 <0>
gs_pdfwr.ps 60 3052856 1711072 1418792 134080 true 1136 4 <0>
END INITFILES 60 3073040 1721109 1418792 134080 true 1164 4 <0>
/usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Init/Fontmap 60 3073040 1724450 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/lib/Fontmap 60 3133592 1769567 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Font/Fontmap 60 3133592 1769616 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/Fontmap 60 3133592 1769652 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/var/lib/ghostscript/fonts/Fontmap 60 3133592 1769686 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/cups/fonts/Fontmap 70 3173960 1797151 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts/Fontmap 70 3173960 1797187 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/local/lib/ghostscript/fonts/Fontmap 70 3173960 1797227 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
/usr/share/fonts/Fontmap 70 3173960 1797251 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <1>
END FONTS 70 3173960 1797324 1418792 135918 true 1165 4 <0>
END DEVICE 70 3759296 2383796 1416984 134110 true 1169 4 <0>
END CONFIG 70 3759296 2384062 1416984 134110 true 1169 4 <0>
Checking.
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Merging.
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Selecting.
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Constructing.
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Putting.
[612.0 792.0]
/.MediaSize
0
/%MediaSource
0
/%MediaDestination
true
/.LockSafetyParams
-mark-
true
-dict-
-device-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Result of putting.
false
-device-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Installing.
false
-device-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
Finishing.
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-dict-
-mark-
-dict-
true
END INIT 80 3819848 2443760 10414560 9129632 true 1179 4 <0>
END GLOBAL 90 3819848 2446400 10414560 9130362 false 1176 4 <0>
END GC 100 3870096 1921230 10434744 9133278 false 1161 3 <0>
```

From what I gather, I first thought it was because I'm missing some fonts that ghostscript depends on to do the conversion.

```
Extend MacRomanEncodingForTrueType for TrueType: cannot insert /Euro @ 219 used for `/currency`
```

### However, I have another server that can convert the pdf, so I figure it has to be some difference in configuration..  So i'm somewhat lost. Any advice why it works on some pdf and doesn't work on some.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

The Ghostscript error seems to be because you don't have X available, and the display device uses X. As to what the problem is with ImageMagick I'm afraid I'm unable to help. Doesn't look like a Ghostscript problem to me though.

Comment: What do you mean by device X?  Where are you reading this from?  Doesn't it clearly indicate that it can't delegate the pdf to jpg which uses ghostscript do the conversion?

Comment: The X-windows server is what I mean by 'X'. The Ghostscript display device uses X-Windows (specifically X11) and the error message you quote "GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting."" looks to me like the result of trying to run GS without X11 support.

Comment: I updated my post, the underlying problem is really with ghostscript.  Its installed but the gs call fails during the converstion and doesn't output a file for imagemagick to process.  Any ideas why that would be?  The open X display is not an issue at all.

Comment: The debug isn't terribly helpful, all you have there is the initialisation and it all appears to be correct. You could try using -dPDFDEBUG but that will just give you a load of baffling information that's useless without the original PDF file. There really isn't anything more I can say without a file to examine. I'd suggest you find a file you can share and open a bug report (bugs.ghostscript.com)